# get attribute information

Tags: c#, reflection

My UI is build with lots of user controls that are translatable. Some controls in the usercontrols shouldn't be translated and I want to tag them as such with a [DoNotTranslate]`  custom attribute.

in my userControl.designer.cs file

```
    [DoNotTranslate] 
    private DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl maxLabel;

    [DoNotTranslate]
    private DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl valueLabel;

    //all other controls
```

The translation function expects a (user)control and then goes through all the child `control.Controls` to make sure all controls are translated without the need to call the translation function on every single control.

Is it possible to find out if a control has my custom attribute set? The problem is that I don't see how I can get the attribute information in the translation function when i go through all the Controls.

Any advice is greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: could you add the code you've written so far (declaration of the custom attribute and the way you're trying to read the information in your translation function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I see now from the code you posted that the attribute is on a property of the control, not on the class defining the control itself. You can try like this:

```
public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetNonTranslatableProperties(WebControl control)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in control.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if(
        property
        .GetCustomAttributes(true)
        .Count(item => item is DoNotTranslateAttribute) > 0)
            yield return property;
    }        
}
```

otherwise, you can subclass Label to a NonTranslatableLabel, apply the attribute to the class and use it instead of Label in your "father" control.

```
[NonTranslatable]
public class NonTranslatableLabel : Label
```

===================

for each of your controls you can do:

```
myCustomControl.GetType()
 .GetCustomAttributes(true)
 .Where(item => item is DoNotTranslateAttribute);
```

for instance you could enumerate all your "non-translatable" controls like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetNonTranslatableChildren(Control control)
{
    foreach(Control c in control.Controls) 
    {
        if(
        c.GetType()
        .GetCustomAttributes(true)
        .Count(item => item is DoNotTranslateAttribute) > 0)
            yield return c;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzdb2077.aspx) method to find out if the attribute has been applied or not. For example,

```
static readonly Type _DoNotTranslateAttribute = typeof(DoNotTranslate);

.... // other code

var t = control.GetType();
if (t.GetCustomAttributes(_DoNotTranslateAttribute, false).length > 0)
{
   // do not translate
}
```

(disclaimer: untested/uncompiled code- just to give an idea how to use the function)

Comment: thx for the response but it's not working for me. With your code don't I check if that specific class (control.GetType()) has the custom attribute applied (attribute on the class and not on the member)?  

In my case my usercontrol has 2 labels I don't want to translate. It's these 2 member labels of that usercontrol I don't want to translate, not the label type itself.

Comment: @Tarscher, you are correct but then your original post was not giving any clue that you wish to apply attribute at property level. Anyway, @paolo had already edited his answer to give the correct solution - IMO, either of that will work.